# No realiza el update con Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

Tengo la siguiente codigo que utiliza la peticion Ajax

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert('Cargando la funcion para update con ajax');
$("button#transferirBien").click(function(e){
    alert('Acceso a la funcion Transferir bien');
        var Id = $("#id").val();
        var Activo= $("#Activo").val();
        var Subactivo = $("#Subactivo").val();
        var Personal = $("#Personal").val();
        var Transferencia = $("#Transferencia").val();
        var Observaciones = $("#Observaciones").val();
alert ('Cargando los  datos'+Id+Activo+Subactivo+Personal);
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "updateBienes.php",
        async:true,
        data: {"Id":Id,"Activo": Activo,"Subactivo": Subactivo, "Personal": Personal},
        success: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
    $("#modalTransferirResguardo").modal('hide');
        bootbox.alert("Transferencia Generadaa Exitosamente!", function() {
        console.log("Alert Callback");  
        location.reload();
        });

        },
        error: function(){
        $("#modalTransferirResguardo").modal('hide');
        bootbox.alert("Error!..No se logro realizar la Transferencia", function() {
        console.log("Alert Callback");  
        location.reload();       
        });
        }
        });
    });
});
```

el detalle es que no hace nada, solo me muestra las alertas con los valores que lleva... el alert(msg) en algunas ocasiones me pone la consulta , al llevar esta a la consola del phpmyadmin o desde un querymysql realiza el update sin problemas

este es mi archivo updatebienes.php

```html
<?PHP
include 'master/clases/cargar_clases.php';

if (isset($_POST['Id']) && $_POST['Activo'] && $_POST['Subactivo'] && $_POST['Personal']){
    echo 'Si aparezco es que si entra hasta aquí';
    $instanciaPersistenciaTransferencia = new transferencia();
    $instanciaNegocioTransferencia = new n_transferencia();
    $resultadoModalTransferencia;
    $totalresultadoModalTransferencia;
    $Id_Bien=strip_tags($_POST['Id']);
    $Activo=strip_tags($_POST['Activo']);
    $Subactivo=strip_tags($_POST['Subactivo']);
    $Numero_Empleado= strip_tags($_POST['Personal']);
    $resultadoModalTransferencia = $instanciaNegocioTransferencia->n_UPdateBienes($Id_Bien,$Activo,$Subactivo,$Numero_Empleado);
    $totalresultadoModalTransferencia=count($resultadoModalTransferencia);
}
?>
```

y esta es mi consulta para realizar el update

```html
public function n_UPdateBienes($Id_Bien,$Activo,$SubActivo,$Numero_Empleado)
        {
        /// Realizar primero el update en la tabla bienes
        $consulta="UPDATE control_patrimonial.bienes SET Numero_Empleado ='$Numero_Empleado' WHERE control_patrimonial.bienes.Id_bien='$Id_Bien' AND control_patrimonial.bienes.Activo='$Activo' AND control_patrimonial.bienes.SubActivo ='$SubActivo'";
        
        //echo $consulta;
        //exit();
        $resultado = $this->consultaAccion($consulta);
        return $resultado;
        
       }
```

Pues haber si me pueden ayudar a resolver este dilema...

Saludos

Comment: te falta el `isset()` en tres variables

Comment: te refieres a esta linea: if (isset($_POST['Id']) && $_POST['Activo'] && $_POST['Subactivo'] && $_POST['Personal']){

Comment: Si, a esa me refiero

Comment: Por que en otra sección utilizo esta linea if (isset($_POST['cantidad'])&& $_POST['cantidad'] >0 && $_POST['empleado'] ){ }y si realiza todo lo que viene ahi....

Comment: Es mejor asegurarse con `isset()` para evitar errores

Comment: @alanfcm deja probar. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

alanfcm, cambie la linea que me indicaste por lo siguiente:

`if (isset($_POST['Id']) || ($_POST['Activo']) || ($_POST['Subactivo']) || ( $_POST['Personal'])){aqui mas codigo}`

Elimine tambien una linea que me marco como un error en donde cargo mis instancias y hago la llamada a la consulta.
Esta linea la comente:

`$totalresultadoModalTransferencia=count($resultadoModalTransferencia);`

supongo que no hay razón para realizar un conteo si no regresa un registro.

Y con eso ya quedo resuelto.

Gracias por tu tiempo :)

Comment: Ojo Puedes tener problemas de seguridad por estar pasando directamente los valores recibidos en el $_POST al query de inserción. Considera usar sentencias preparadas.

Comment: @quevedo Voy a tomar en cuenta tu comentario, solo que tendría que investigar lo de las sentencias preparadas. Saludos

Comment: Como estás usando PHP esta guía te puede servir [The only proper - PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)

Comment: @quevedo Gracias lo voy a revisar :)